# JDBC Batch Updates for multiple tables

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have to update 10 odd tables in one go, they should be updated each time a row is processed ( a message is created which can be of one or more rows). 
Database: Oracle 12cR2

Is there a way using JdbC BatchUpdate and PreparedStatement we can do this??

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use a single stored procedure that populates the different tables, and batch the parameter sets for that procedure. I'm not sure if that'll work though.

Comment: Do you perhaps look for using a trigger?